# How to find substrings in a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find if exists a substring in a list of strings,
FOR EXAMPLE:

I have the list of words `['GGBASDEPINK','ASDEKNIP','PINK','WORDRRAB','BAR']`

PINK is a substring of ASDEKNIP , because the reverse of PINK is KNIP
and the word BAR is in WORDRRAB because the reverse is RAB

How to find if substrip is exits? and if yes so put in reverse that string
so the new list should be:

```
d = ['GGBASDEPINK','ASDEKNIP','PINK','WORDRRAB','BAR' ,'KNIP', 'RAB']
```

I tried like this

```
d = ['GGBASDEPINK','ASDEKNIP','PINK','WORDRRAB','BAR']
for word in d:
    word = word[::-1]
    if word in d:
        print(word)
```

But it gives nothing

Comment: @balki d = ['GGBASDEPINK','ASDEKNIP','PINK','WORDRRAB','BAR' ,'KNIP', 'RAB']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

d = ['GGBASDEPINK','ASDEKNIP','PINK','WORDRRAB','BAR']

for x, y in permutations(d, 2):
    rev = y[::-1]
    if rev in x:
        d.append(rev)

print(d)
# ['GGBASDEPINK', 'ASDEKNIP', 'PINK', 'WORDRRAB', 'BAR', 'KNIP', 'RAB']
```

Comment: "for x, y in permutations(d, 2):" What does mean the number 2?

Comment: For long lists, you will save a lot of work using `combinations` and check `shorter in longer`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I believe that doesn't test every words, since it's shorter like you say, ofcourse it works in this example.

Comment: @LordNord, Taking 2 words at a time.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I have for example 100 words, which I don't know how many of the words can contain those sub-strings, What do you suggest?

Comment: Combinations catches all pairs once. Permutations catches all pairs twice. But only the shorter of the two involved strings can be a substring of the other, so one comparison is spurious. But for pairs the gain is marginal, as the iterations will just half while you add a comparison of lengthes.